# Problems with Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

It throws error in the debug build, and freezes in the release.

Debug building runs finely, but then I try to run compiled executable, it gives me `this application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect`.

Releaze building freezes the whole studio, executable gives me `Test.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error - Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application.`. No idea why C++ app requires .NET.

Any ideas of what's going on here, other that I should get some other version of studio?

Comment: Visual Studio uses .NET in the UI/etc...  try re-installing .NET or Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you running VS9SP1 or SP0.  If SP0, get SP1.  Otherwise Get Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645 and get it to track what test.exe is doing when trying to load.  Is it looking for test.exe.2.config?  Try reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374182(v=vs.85).aspx - it may tell you what the fix is.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29
here's a link to download what you need to stop that errors, try this i think will help you to get rid of the bug..

Comment: Yes, installed that, nothing changed. I wonder what libraries and where it installed. Maybe if i'll place them in the same folder with executable, it will work...

Comment: try that.. or better deinstall and install a newer visual studio.. you really need that 2008 version? or that is only your lincesed version? if you have license i understand but if you have a cracked one go get an install another one, i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Didn't You create CLI Console App? If yes create Win32 Console App, because it's not using Managed Code, which requires .Net.